# Trocar de lugar senha e email

Tags: text

Estou com um banco de dados de 5 mil usuario e emails no seguinte formato:

senha|email
senha|email
senha|email
senha|email
senha|email

Preciso trocar colocar email em primeiro é simples mais não consigo. preciso deixar nesse formato

email|senha

Comment: Você quer trocar a ordem das colunas? Qual seu SGBD?

Comment: Informe para nós o seu SGBD.

Comment: é um arquivo txt nesse formato eu nao manjo de programação só queria inverter a ordem no arquivo txt

Comment: so abrir com o editor de texto e mudar a ordem

Comment: Como ? não ja tentei nao consigo notepad++ faz isso?

Comment: Você pode usar o Sublime Text de repente, ou o Excel. Tudo vai depender de como está formatado seu BD, se tem tabulações ou não..

Comment: Já que vai fazer uma mudança dessas, considere mudar o modelo de segurança como um todo.

Comment: Consegui obrigado Niko Bellic usei o excel fiz em tabelas e inverte era simples =D